# Confused with logic

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have taken a picture of the solution to the proof of the following question.

> Let $X$ be a topological space. A family of subsets $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ of $X$ is said to have the finite interseciton properyty if for all finite $J \subseteq I$, the intersection $\cap V_j$ is nonempty. Prove that $X$ is compact if and only if it has the property that for every family of closed subsets $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ of $X$ with the finite intersection property, $\cap V_i$ is nonempty.

Now the proof is as follows

[image]

What I don't understand is, the if and only if statements,

> for all families $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ of closed subsets of $X$, $\cap V_i = \phi \Rightarrow \exists$ finite $J \subseteq I$ such that $\cap V_j = \phi$

if and only if

> for all families $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ of closed subsets of $X$, ($\not\exists$ finite $J \subseteq I$ such that $\cap V_j = \phi$) $\Rightarrow$ $\cap V_i \neq \phi$

..Didn't the preceding statement say that, in words, that for all $i \in I$, the intersection of $V_i$s will be empty i.e. nothing in common between them, which clearly implies that taking the subset $J \subseteq I$ which is smaller, will also have an empty intersection $\cap V_j = \phi$? Why does this "if and only if" that, suddenly, say in the second statement that "there exists **NO SUCH** $J \subseteq I$ such that $\cap V_j \not= \phi$"? Aren't the statements *exact* contradictions/opposites of one another?

The logic doesn't follow for me, can someone beak it down and explain please?

Comment: The first says that for all families of closed sets, $P\implies Q$; the second says that for all families of closed sets, $\neg Q\implies\neg P$. Since the implication $P\implies Q$ and its contrapositive $\neg Q\implies\neg P$ are logically equivalent, so are these two statements.

Comment: The second implication is the contrapositive of the first. Hence it is equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is when you write "which clearly implies . . ." You seem to assume, there, that taking an intersection of a *smaller* collection of sets results in a *smaller* set.

But the opposite is true in general: if $J\subseteq I$, we have $\bigcap_{k\in J}V_k$ is **bigger** *(well, can be bigger - certainly is no smaller)* than $\bigcap_{k\in I}V_k$! For example, take the three sets $$V_1=\{2, 3\}, V_2=\{1, 3\}, V_3=\{1, 2\}.$$ Then $V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3=\emptyset$, but $V_1\cap V_2=\{3\}$.

The statement in question says that any time I take a bunch of closed sets whose intersection is empty, some finite number of them already had empty intersection. This is definitely not true in general. For example, take $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology and let $V_i=\{i, i+1, i+2, . . .\}=[i, \infty).$ Then

- $\bigcap V_i=\emptyset$, but
- for any finite family of $V_i$s, their intersection is nonempty; e.g. $V_1\cap V_2\cap . . .\cap V_{71234} $ contains $71234$.

Or, an example related to a previous question you asked: in the subspace topology on $(0, 1)$, the sets $(0, \epsilon]$ are closed for each $\epsilon\in (0, 1)$.  Let $V_i=(0, {1\over i}]$; then

- $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}V_i=\emptyset$, but
- any finitely many $V_i$s have nonempty intersection.

(Note that the first bullet point is a fancy way of saying "$\{({1\over n}, 1): n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover of $(0, 1)$," and the second bullet point says it has no finite subcover!)

Comment: Feels like a step closer but still confused; so for this question I have in particular, it's saying "If some $\cap V_i = \phi$ then it means already some finite $J \subseteq I$ had $\cap V_j = \phi$ **IFF** on the contrary there was *no* such $J \subseteq I$ that allows $\cap V_j = \phi$, then it must be that $\cap V_i \neq \phi$"??

Comment: @JohnTrail Yes, this is the *contrapositive*: a statement "if $A$ then $B$" is equivalent to "if *not $B$* then *not $A$*." For instance, "if it is raining, I'm getting wet" is equivalent to "if I'm not getting wet, it's not raining." Your "on the contrary" is not warranted: the two statements are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement says: if a family of closed sets has empty intersection, then already a finite subset of them had finite intersection.

This is the only non-trivial implication in that iff statement, because if finitely many of them already have empty intersection - so there is no point in all finitely many of them at the same time - then there is certainly (*a fortiori* with a nice term) no point in *all* of them at the same time.

In other words: there is a "finite reason" for the empty intersection of the whole family of closed sets.

The second statement reformulates this: if you want to guarantee that the total intersection of closed sets is non-empty, then it is enough to garantuee that every finite subfamily has non-empty intersection. This is exactly true for the previous reason: if you take away all finite reasons for empty intersections then there is no empty intersection at all. So assuming the first statement leads to the second and vice versa.

It's an example of the contrapositive being used (as the proof formulates it).